# Building a List within Conversation Scoped Bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces, cdi

I am having an issue with Primefaces 5 and JSF 2.1.

Can't post code right now as I'm on my tablet but I will give a basic description and upload code later.

I have a `ConversationScoped` CDI bean and a JSF page with 5 text field, mapped to an entity, a primefaces dataView and a button.  What I want to do is keep adding the data from the fields into the dataView.

I have a List in the bean class say, `private List<dataEntity> data = new ArrayList<dataEntity>`.

and I have a method that is triggered by pressing the button that adds the data to the array, but every time I add data, all the entries in the List are replaced with the latest entry.

Essentially the list contains N copies of the Nth entry

I thought about saving each entry to the database fist and populating the List from that but it seems illogical to be.

This has stumped me for the last two days.  Can anyone suggest some solutions to this problem. I want to use CDI beans rather than JSF Managed if at all possible.

Thanks

Comment: post your code and clarify what you mean by all the entries are replaced

Comment: When do you start the conversation? Have you marked it as long running? With every button press, if the conversation is not long running, nor the cid is not present with the next request, your conversationscoped bean is effectively are requestscoped beans

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no code here, I will have to take a few guesses but I think the problem is your `@ConversationScoped` bean, or rather the understanding of it's lifecycle.

Unless you make the conversation long running, this scope will behave equally to `@RequestScoped` - it will be thrown away after each request and created anew upon new one.Which means the `List` within it will be re-created every time.

What you want here is either making the conversation long running, which you usually do in the following way:

```
@ConversationScoped
public class YourBean {

    @Inject Conversation conversation

    // call this sometime within the first request
    public void conversationStartingMethod() {
        conversation.begin();
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can make your bean `@SessionScoped` instead, which will make it live for the whole HTTP session (or unless timeout/invalidation).

Comment: Sorry for no code, I'm traveling atm and have no computer access.  My conversation starts fine but when I add the first item to the List it functions fine so I get one entry of type dataEntity, say e1 but when I add a second entry, say e2, the List then contains two entries but both are e2 and so on a so forth.  Essentially the list contains N of the Nth entry

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. I will wait until you post code - this sounds more like some tiny bug in your code (the way you store it into list) rather than anything else.